# Computing norms of positive maps

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite

Suppose $\Phi: S_n \to S_n$ is a positive linear map on symmetric matrices. As a consequence of Russo-Dye theorem we know that

$$\|\Phi\|=\|\Phi(I)\|$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm, ie section 2.5 [here](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Elessa/tesis/Positive%20Definite%20Matrices.pdf).

I'm instead interested in $\|\cdot\|_1$, the trace norm (sum of singular values), how do I compute induced operator norm in such case?

Comment: Note that, as is done in the reference you give, it is more common to define $\Phi$ as a map over **Hermitian** (rather than symmetric) matrices with possibly complex entries. I am not sure if every positive map over real symmetric matrices unique extends to a positive map over Hermitian matrices.

Comment: As I stated in a comment on your previous question, I think you should open a new question that explains the specifics of your map and why it would be helpful to compute its trace norm.

Comment: Here's the separate question with the background -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818716/when-is-sgd-for-linear-least-squares-stable

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting it, looks like an interesting problem (though I can see why you might have been hesitant to write it all out). I'll be sure to leave a comment or answer if I have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose that, contrary to what your reference indicates, you are indeed interested in a map that is positive over the real symmetric matrices.

The "brute force" approach to computing the trace norm would be as follows. Let $E_{ij}$ denote the size $n$ matrix with a $1$ in the $i,j$ entry and zeros elsewhere. Define
$$
B_{ij} = \begin{cases}
E_{ii} & i=j\\
\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(E_{ij} + E_{ji}) & i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
We see that $B_{ij}$ forms an orthonormal basis on $S_n$ relative to the inner product defined by $\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB)$. Let $\mathcal B$ denote the basis $\mathcal B = \{B_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\}$, where the tuples $i,j$ are taken in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Define $f : \{(i,j): 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\} \to \{1,\dots,n(n+1)/2\}$ to be the associated counting function, so that
$$
f(1,1) = 1, \quad f(1,2) = 2,\dots, f(2,1) = n+1, \dots, f(n,n) = n(n+1)/2.
$$
Let $M$ denote the size $n(n+1)/2$ matrix of $\Phi$ relative to $\mathcal B$. The entries of $M$ satisfy
$$
M_{\phi(i,j),\phi(p,q)} = \langle \Phi(B_{ij}),\Phi(B_{pq})\rangle.
$$
The trace norm of $\Phi$ is equal to the trace norm of $M$.

Comment: Thanks, is there a standard reference which derives this connection?

Comment: I may be missing something because for identity operator, this calculation me value greater than 1. I found eq 20.3 in these class notes relevant -- https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/LectureNotes/CS766.Fall2011/20.pdf

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov We're talking about different norms. In that context, $\|\cdot\|_1$ refers to the "induced $1$-norm", as defined in equation 20.1. My calculation is of the trace norm of the linear map $\Phi$ itself.

Comment: Got it. Interestingly, the author calls the theorem for computing induced trace-norms "Russo-Dye" -- Theorem 3.39 on page 167 of https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/TQI.pdf

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov The true [Russo-Dye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo%E2%80%93Dye_theorem) theorem is a statement about unitary matrices/operators. Presumably, these other results are given that name because they are in some sense direct consequences of this theorem.

Comment: I see. One thing I couldn't find in that book is a Russo-Dye equivalent for induced Frobenius norm. The elegant equation in Lemma 1 of https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/aistats_defossez_bach_with_supp.pdf seems to be the condition for induced Frobenius norm to be 1, but the derivation is complicated