# when is SGD for linear least squares stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $Y$ another random variable with values in $\mathbb{R}$. We wish to solve the following optimization problem.

$$\min_{w\in \mathbb{R}^d} \mathbb{E}[\|X^Tw-Y\|^2]$$

Our random variables $(X,Y)$ are jointly sampled from a fixed set of $n$ observations $(x_1,y_1),\ldots , (x_n,y_n)$ , uniformly, with replacement. We solve corresponding minimization problem by using stochastic gradient descent with step size $\alpha$.

Step 0: initialize $w$ to a some initial vector $w_0$

Step $k$: sample a random observation pair $(x_{i_k}, y_{i_k})$ and apply gradient descent step
$$w_{k+1}=w_k-\alpha f_{i_k}'(w)$$

where $f_{i_k}(w)=\frac{1}{2}\|x_{i_k}'w-y_{i_k}\|^2$ .

Suppose there exists a unique $w^*$ which achieves 0 loss for every observation pair. For which values of $\alpha$ does our procedure converge to $w^*$?

To examine this we can look at behavior of $\eta_k=w_k-w^*$. It can be shown that $k$'th step of gradient descent transforms this quantity as follows:

$$\eta_{k+1}=(I-\alpha X_{i_k} X_{i_k}')\eta_k$$

We are then interested  in the values of $\alpha$ such that  $\mathbb{E}[\|\eta_k\|^2]$ converges to 0 as $k\to \infty$. Writing this as as $\text{tr }\eta \eta'$, we rephrase the question as follows -- for which values of $\alpha$ is the following operator $T$ contractive in trace norm?

$$T(x) = E (I-\alpha XX') x (I-\alpha XX') $$

(if we were instead interested in the operator norm, applying Russo-Dye theorem would give us the following necessary and sufficient condition)

$$\alpha < \left\|\frac{2 E[XX']}{E[XX'XX']}\right\|$$